# Navbar is stretched in full height only on Safari

Tags: css, safari

I've got a navbar that looks briliant in all browsers except on Safari - it's stretched at full screen height (but not width). 
In all browser it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9noX.jpg

[image]
And in Safari...well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFDsa.jpg

[image]

My first assumptions and suspicions are `position:sticky`, `linear-gradient` and `box-shadow` but it's only my suspicions.
Not even sure whether it is a CSS problem. I use also react-scroller there, so my that's the issue?

Here is my SCSS code:

Navbar general:

```
.thematic-area-nav {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  width: 70vw;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 1px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 1px #000000;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    from($color-background-primary),
    color-stop(50%, rgb(237, 237, 237)),
    to($color-background-primary)
  );
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    top,
    $color-background-primary 0%,
    rgb(237, 237, 237) 50%,
    $color-background-primary 100%
  );
  background: -o-linear-gradient(
    top,
    $color-background-primary 0%,
    rgb(237, 237, 237) 50%,
    $color-background-primary 100%
  );
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    $color-background-primary 0%,
    rgb(237, 237, 237) 50%,
    $color-background-primary 100%
  );
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;

  & > * {
    color: black;
  }

  & > ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 25% auto;
    grid-template-columns: 25% auto;
  }
}
```

Logo:

```
.thematic-area-nav__logo {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  -ms-grid-row-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150%;
}
```

Buttons:

```
.thematic-area-nav__areas {
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 1;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(12vw, 16vw));
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  & > button {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(218, 218, 218);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(218, 218, 218);
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px;
    background-color: $color-background-primary;
    font-size: 1vw;
    &:hover {
      color: black;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px;
      box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    &:focus {
      outline: none;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px;
      box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }
}
.thematic-area-nav__singleThematicArea {
  & a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
  & > * {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
  }
}
```

Is that a CSS problem indeed?

Comment: Could you possibly create a jsbin allowing to reproduce and debug the problem? I'd love to help. What looks suspicious to me is the use of css grid for seemingly simple design concept. Why did you chose that particular way of laying out the buttons? From my experience, position sticky tends to be cumbersome as well, however I do not have a specific and well documented reason for that belief.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/rasexud/edit?html,css,output -> it's hard to reproduce because it's a react component with some imports and so on. Even Codesandbox doesn't help  ;) 
You may be right that CSS Grid is a little overhead.
I'm using a react-scroll for scrolling effect - I can't find any issues like that, but maybe that's the problem? I'll checkout this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the html/scss code from jsbin, did some cleanup and managed to achieve something I think is close to what you had in mind.

Some notes:

Avoid using vw and vh for font sizes unless there is a really good reason not to do so.

If specifying width/height in % always figure out how the browser calculates those (ask yourself "percentage of what?").

Use https://validator.w3.org/ - it helps.

Avoid mixing camelCase and-this__thingy.

Keep your code tidy.

HTML

```
<div class="thematic-area-nav">
  <div class="thematic-area-nav__logo-wrapper">
    <img class="thematic-area-nav__logo" src="https://picsum.photos/200/90" alt="Logo Coaching People">
  </div>
  <ul class="thematic-area-nav__areas">
    <li class="thematic-area-nav__singleThematicArea"><a class="Obszar tematyczny 1">Obszar tematyczny 1</a></li>
    <li class="thematic-area-nav__singleThematicArea"><a class="Obszar tematyczny 2">Obszar tematyczny 2</a></li>
    <li class="thematic-area-nav__singleThematicArea"><a class="Obszar tematyczny 3">Obszar tematyczny 3</a></li>
    <li class="thematic-area-nav__singleThematicArea"><a class="Obszar tematyczny 4">Obszar tematyczny 4</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

SCSS

```
.thematic-area-nav {
  position: sticky;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 1px #000000;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    from($color-background-primary),
    color-stop(50%, rgb(237, 237, 237)),
    to($color-background-primary)
  );
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
  justify-content: space-between;
  @media (max-width: 420px) {
    display: block;
  }
 }

.thematic-area-nav__logo-wrapper {
   @media (max-width: 420px) {
     text-align: center;
     margin-bottom: .6em;
  }
}
.thematic-area-nav__areas {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex: 1;
}

.thematic-area-nav__singleThematicArea {
    padding: .6em 1em;
    margin-bottom: .6em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(218, 218, 218);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(218, 218, 218);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px;
    background-color: $color-background-primary;
    &:hover {
      color: black;
      box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px;
    }
    &:focus {
      outline: none;
      box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s quite unlikely that react code is causing the problem. Could you copy the html that is created by your react application, the css code and create a test case with just those? It would be good to establish if the problem appears when your JS is not “enabled”. How do you feel about sharing a link to your repo?

Some side notes: putting a link inside a button does not seem right. It will most definitely fail any accessibility evaluation, also class="Obszar tematyczny 3”  value doesn’t seem right, ul element should only have li as children, placing anything else inside it is, well, WRONG.

There is also quite a lot of flex box weirdness in your styles. By reading it I’m not really able to grasp your intentions. I think that you’re not fully familiar with flexbox properties that belong to flex container and those that belong to its children.

In addition to that, you could stop using * selector. Just stop. World will be a better place if you do.

Comment: Notsomuch - thanks for you advices, I'll implement them ASAP!
https://github.com/KamilSobieraj/Konfigurator_szkolen -> here is my repo. It's not up to date, but there is the problem as well. A navbar component is in src->components/nabar_components/thematci_area_nav.jsx
And one big and important disclaimer - there is only one .scss file for all components. Please, don't ask me why is that, it's on my urgent list to make it right... The file is in src/index.scss.
https://konfiguratorszkolen.pl/ -> here is a "life" demo ;)